# "Mitkommen" means to come or to go?

Tags: translation

What is the meaning of the following sentence: *wir kommen gerne mit ins Kino*

And the main question: does the verb *mitkommen* here mean *to go* or *to come*?

Comment: Hi, you seem to be asking not about the meaning of the German sentence, but about the best English formulation. If that is the case, then the question is off-topic here. If this is not the case, then please edit and clarify your question.

Comment: So sorry, it's not the case, but I'm confused between these two meaning,  I'll edit my question

Comment: I highly doubt the meaning,  what if the whole sentence is wrong :/

Comment: @LeonMeier sorry, but no. German is very flexible with word order and the given example is perfectly fine.

Comment: @LeonMeier still, claiming that the sentence is *wrong* is incorrect.

Comment: I get it,  it's grammatically correct,  but as a beginner I better use the other structure that @leonMeier told me about

Answer (score 10):

Neither.

*Mitkommen* means to *join someone* or *follow someone* in the movement, without specifying the direction. Therefore it can be used

- when you leave from wherever you are together
- or go to a place together.
- It can also be used figuratively if you (can't) follow someone's line of thought or explanation.

As so often context is key, so in your example, the speaker agrees to join the addressee on the way to the cinema.

Comment: Thanks, I found this sentence in the essential book of "living language", the translation was "we gladly come to the movies". It doesn't make sense to me so I came here to ask about it hoping to find an accurate meaning to it.

Comment: Interestingly, Scandinavian languages have a similar construction, and North American dialects have adapted it as “to come with”.

Answer (score 3):

The prefix *mit-*, that succeeds some German verbs and nouns, seems to be difficult to understand to English native speakers. I think a good way to understand it, is to translate is as *co-* in the sense of *accompany* or *go with*.

A *Mitarbeiter* is a *co-worker*, i.e someone, who works together with another worker.

If someone is singing, and other people start singing together with the first person, then this is *mitsingen* (think of it as *to co-sing*).

And also:
The German verb *kommen* is *to come* or *to go* in English. Then *mitkommen* is *to co-come* or *to co-go*. This means: To come along with someone.

If you have this in mind, its easy to translate

> Wir kommen gerne mit ins Kino.

In a first step it is:

> We like to *co-go* to the cinema.

This means: Someone wants to go to the cinema, and *we* want to *co-go* with this person, i.e. we want to accompany this person. So you can translate it as:

> We want to **accompany** *the person who wanted to go*.
>   We want to **come along with** *the person who wanted to go*.

But note, that in this English translation you have to say who you want to accompany. You don't need to say this in German. And when you say this in English, it is hard to insert the target of the movement into the sentence. This doesn't sound like good English to me:

> We want to **accompany** you *to the cinema.*

But you can omit the target in German too. It is not mandatory. So this is correct too:

> Wir kommen gerne mit.

Comment: You always provide me with best answers، million thanks

Answer (score 1):

The best English equivalent of *mitkommen* is *to come along*

Comment: Apparently, this is the best translation I got for this verb.  what translation do you suggest for the whole sentence?  Thank you

Comment: It tanslates to _We're glad to come along to the movie theater_

Comment: One last question,  does the following sentence serve the same meaning (we like to go to the movie theater)

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. "We like to go to the movie theater" implies that we like going to the movie theater **in general** (i.e. any day, any time), meanwhile, the original sentence only says that we're glad to go **now** (i.e. with **this occasion**)

Comment: Aha, now it makes much more sense. This explanation made it clear to me now